# How to write method in automapper class c#

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to write method in AutoMapper class. My situation is as below.

```
ClinicListVm = AutoMapperConfig.mapper
  .Map<GetClinicsByUserName_Result, ClinicListViewModel>(c);
```

I already map ClinicListViewModel with GetClinicsByUserName_Result now I want to manipulate one attribute my destination model as below.

```
ClinicListVm.ProgressBarCssClass = string.Empty;
if (ClinicListVm.PercentComplete == 100)
{
  ClinicListVm.ProgressBarCssClass = "progress-bar-success";
}
else if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(ClinicListVm.BillerStartDateTime ?? DateTime.Now).TotalDays > MaxDaysInDataEntry)
{
  // partial is a warning color
  ClinicListVm.ProgressBarCssClass = "progress-bar-partial";
}
```

So, How I can include this code it self in automapper class.

Thanks

Comment: AutoMapper is not the place to do it. Such logic has nothing to do with mapping objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally think @Rajmond Burgaj's anwer is a good one. Using a ResolveUsing(), or a custom resolver, is in this case a good way to go.

However, I just want to share a more pragmatic alternative that may result in the same and *might* help you in the future. You may want to consider abstracting the conditional if...then... logic to a seperate function. For example:

```cs
private string DetermineProgressBarState(SourceClass source)
{
    if (source.PercentComplete == 100) return "progress-bar-success";

    var MaxDaysInDataEntry = 42; // missing in your sample
    return DateTime.Now.Subtract(source.BillerStartDateTime ?? DateTime.Now).TotalDays > MaxDaysInDataEntry 
        ? "progress-bar-partial" 
        : null;
}
```

With that, you can easily map it in your configuration, like so:

```cs
Mapper.Initialize((config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<SourceClass, TargetClass>()
        .ForMember(
            dest => dest.ProgressBarCssClass, 
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>  DetermineProgressBarState(src))
        );
}));
```

This runs exactly as you'd expect. Here is the full sample, as a XUnit test (but you'll get the picture):

```cs
public class SourceClass
{
    public int PercentComplete { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BillerStartDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class TargetClass
{
    public string ProgressBarCssClass { get; set; }
}

public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // arrange - configure the automapper
        Mapper.Initialize((config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<SourceClass, TargetClass>()
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.ProgressBarCssClass, 
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>  DetermineProgressBarState(src))
                );
        }));

        // arrange - create a 
        var source = new SourceClass() { PercentComplete = 100 };

        // act - map source to target
        var target = Mapper.Map<TargetClass>(source);

        // assert - verify the result
        target.ProgressBarCssClass.Should().Be("progress-bar-success");
    }

    private string DetermineProgressBarState(SourceClass source)
    {
        if (source.PercentComplete == 100) return "progress-bar-success";

        var MaxDaysInDataEntry = 42; // missing in your sample
        return DateTime.Now.Subtract(source.BillerStartDateTime ?? DateTime.Now).TotalDays > MaxDaysInDataEntry 
            ? "progress-bar-partial" 
            : null;
    }
}
```

**But...** I totally agree with the comment that **AutoMapper is not the place to put this logic in**. The reason is that you're actually defining markup logic (html/css data) in your mapping logic. This is better placed inside your view, presumably your .cshtml.

With that in mind, should you choose to refactor this somehow "the proper way" in the future, the `DetermineProgressBarState()` function will still be helpful. You'll just move the code from your AutoMapper config to your controller (or .cshtml helper).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute another function while mapping you can use `ResolveUsing` method and put your logic in there.

```
CreateMap<GetClinicsByUserName_Result, ClinicListViewModel>()
.ForMember(d => d.ProgressBarCssClass , o => o.ResolveUsing(s =>
{
    //Do your custom logic here.
}))
.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
{
   //Do your logical after mapping has been done
    dest.ProgressBarCssClass = string.Empty;
    if (dest.PercentComplete == 100)
    {
       dest.ProgressBarCssClass = "progress-bar-success";
    }
    else if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(dest.BillerStartDateTime ?? 
    DateTime.Now).TotalDays > MaxDaysInDataEntry)
    {
       // partial is a warning color
       dest.ProgressBarCssClass = "progress-bar-partial";
    }      
});
```

Not quite sure where that `MaxDaysInDataEntry` is coming from but if it can be retrieved inside this method your are good to go this way otherwise if `MaxDaysInDataEntry` is a variable generated from business logic elsewhere then it is a problem!

Anyway let me know if it help and where that variable is coming from!